# nodejs wait until all MongoDB calls in loop finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I'm reading a data stream from a CSV file row by row, and calling a findOne MongoDB call on each row, how can I wait till all the mongo calls from each row are complete before I run the next function?

I've seen Promises can do it? But I find Promises extremely difficult to understand. And none of the examples I've found seem to cover what I'm trying to it. :/

```
var validProducts = [];

fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
  .pipe(csvStream)
  .on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  })
  // loop through all rows
  .on('data', function (data) {
    if (data.size === 'a3') {
      ProductModel.findOne({ sku: data.sku }, function (err, product) {
        if (product !== null) {
          product.size = data.size;
          product.save();
          validProducts.push(product);
        }
      });
    }
  });

// on finish make call to other function
socket.emit({ 'status': 'complete' });
otherFunction(validProducts);
```

`on('finish')` or `on('end')` will only call at the end of the data stream, not after the Monogo calls.

If I can use promises, can someone please explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) API witch allows you to make promises. There is an interesting function that allows you to wait for an array of promises to be resolved. Here is an example of how you could solve your problem with `Q.all`:

```
var validProducts = [];
var promises = [];

function handleData(data) {
    if (data.size === 'a3') {

        var deferred = Q.defer();

        ProductModel.findOne({ sku: data.sku }, function (err, product) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(new Error(err));
            }

            if (product) {
                product.size = data.size;
                product.save();
                deferred.resolve(product);
                validProducts.push(product);
            }

        });

        promises.push(deferred.promise);

    }
}

function handleEnd() {
    Q.all(promises).done(function (values) {
        socket.emit({ 'status': 'complete' });
        otherFunction(validProducts);
    });
}

fs.createReadStream(req.file.path)
  .on('data', handleData)
  .on('end', handleEnd);
```

Comment: :P I was so close to this on my own,. but didn't setup the deferred stuff right.

Comment: this wont `wait till all the mongo calls from each row are complete before I run the next function` at all

Comment: Maybe my logic is flawed? Correct me if i'm wrong but when there is no more data to read from the file, we are waiting for all the promises to be resolved before executing the specified functions.

Comment: If I'm right in my way of thinking, the stream will `end` before anything has been added to the `promises` array. So `Q.all(promises)` will execute instantly. :/

Comment: I copied ur answer wrong, I had it pushing the deferred promise INSIDE the mongo call, that'd never work. But ur example was outside. Silly me. It works it works! Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually there was a typo initially! I edited it and I thought it would go unnoticed. It was a pleasure ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [pause](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause)/[resume](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume)

```
  .on('data', function (data) {
    if (data.size === 'a3') {
      this.pause(); // pause it
      var stream = this; // save 'this'
      ProductModel.findOne({ sku: data.sku }, function (err, product) {
        if (product !== null) {
          product.size = data.size;
          product.save();
          validProducts.push(product);
        }
        stream.resume(); //resume it
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: doesn't this make the function synchronous, not asynchronous?

Comment: Close. But the `.resume()` and `.push()` need to happen inside the callback from `.save()`. Also not sure that `this` is exposed, so you likely need to grab the stream externally first.

Comment: It's an I/O function for a database. Just about all I/O in node is async, or should be.

Comment: I actually think I have no clue what the question is :D - I thought `each row` was being processed by the `on('data'` function

Comment: the I/O is async, but only one mongo call will happen at once if the stream is paused until the previous one finishes, which makes it Synchronous (technically), while also (technically) answer my question..ish.

Comment: You still got it right. It's processing a stream, so pause and resume control the flow. The `end` event will signify when the end of stream is met but by controlling with "pause/resume" in the async parts you are sure they have completed when the stream end is reached. That was the basic principle even if you didn't understand the other part.

Comment: @Ezra - did I understand correctly that you did want to pause the stream while the mongo call was in flight, then resume it when that call was completed? it doesn't make the function synchronous at all, it's just controlling the flow of incoming data during other asynchronous code

Comment: @JaromandaX, I was not trying to pause the stream, just wait for the async code in each `on('data')` loop to finished before continuing. Maybe "synchronous" was the wrong way to say it, I haven't tried it, but I am assuming that if you "pause" a stream you are "blocking" it from continuing, just not blocking anything else.

Comment: I can't tell if my answer is at all useful or not, I'm getting mixed signals

Comment: I does look like it would solve my problem, though its not the answer I was hoping for. :P

Comment: *Attaching a data event listener to a stream that has not been explicitly paused will switch the stream into flowing mode* **Data will then be passed as soon as it is available** - seems you WANT to pause that because it will trigger "as fast as possible"